# Replace all trailing spaces before a specific char

Tags: c#, regex

I'm parsing snort rules which are notorious for having all kinds of characters. What I'm trying to replace specifically are all the trailing spaces that precede the last closing parenthesis with simply a closing parenthesis:

simple example:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "jons test";     flow: to_server,established;     content:"/ui/"; nocase;    content:"/getlatestversion?ver=";  nocase;   sid:1002496; rev:1;      )
```

Should be:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "jons test";     flow: to_server,established;     content:"/ui/"; nocase;    content:"/getlatestversion?ver=";  nocase;   sid:1002496; rev:1;)
```

I've tried

```
string newRuleText = Regex.Replace(this.textBox1.Text, "s+\\)$", ")");
```

and

```
 string newRuleText = Regex.Replace(this.textBox1.Text, "\\s+\\)$", ")");
```

But the newRuleText string still has no changes.

Comment: Are there even more spaces after the closing parenthesis?

Comment: @GrantWinney How did you get it to work? I added this in a simple form: textBox2.Text = newRuleText; but the new textBox2 still looks the exact same as textBox1... what did I miss?

Comment: @SinaIravanian None. The string is exactly as seen, where the last parenthesis in the snort rule is the last parenthesis in the string.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @GrantWinney Very odd... I did the same with the following button click handler. And all I did was paste what I have in this post into textbox1: `string newRuleText = Regex.Replace(this.textBox1.Text, "\\s+\\)$", ")");
            textBox2.Text = newRuleText;`

Comment: @GrantWinney it does work... I missed something really simple somehow in a copy paste I think. Sorry to take your time on this easy problem, how should mark this? Answered by Grant or by myself, haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related with the regular expression which is right. I've executed this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: \"jons test\";     flow: to_server,established;     content:\"/ui/\"; nocase;    content:\"/getlatestversion?ver=\";  nocase;   sid:1002496; rev:1;      )","\\s+\\)$",")")
```

and the result was:

```
"alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: \"jons test\";     flow: to_server,established;     content:\"/ui/\"; nocase;    content:\"/getlatestversion?ver=\";  nocase;   sid:1002496; rev:1;)"
```

May be the ")" is not the last character of the string.

Did you test with "\s+\)"?

If this works then the problem is related with the $, and the ")" is not the last character

Comment: Interesting, let me go over my data slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Pablo, there was a copy / paste error that caused this issue, as you stated the regular expression was correct.